# Web3J - Creation of Light Wallet takes too long

Tags: android, blockchain, ethereum, web3-java

I am creating the wallet in my Android app, using the library Web3j: https://web3j.io/

See the code:

```
String seed = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
ECKeyPair exKey = Keys.createEcKeyPair();

WalletFile wallet = Wallet.createLight(seed,exKey);
```

It is creating the Wallet properly, the problem is that the process takes long time, around 10 minutes.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there another way to make it faster?

Answer (score 1):

To generate the wallet I change the method:

```
WalletFile wallet = Wallet.createLight(String seed, ECKeyPair exKey);
```

For the following method:

```
WalletFile wallet = Wallet.create(String seed,ECKeyPair exKey, int n, int p);
```

Which is much more faster than the createLight (It was 10 minutes, and now is few second).

Answer (score -1):

You should be creating a wallet this way:

```
try {
    ECKeyPair ecKeyPair = Keys.createEcKeyPair();
    BigInteger privateKeyInDec = ecKeyPair.getPrivateKey();
    String sPrivatekeyInHex = privateKeyInDec.toString(16);

    WalletFile aWallet = Wallet.createLight(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), ecKeyPair);
    String sAddress = aWallet.getAddress();
} catch (CipherException e | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e | NoSuchAlgorithmException e | NoSuchProviderException e) {
    //
}
```

Comment: What's the difference? In the method Wallet.createLight we are passing the same arguments.

Comment: The difference is that in one you are creating a light wallet and the other you are not.

Comment: I am sorry maybe I am missing something, this is your line for the wallet creation: WalletFile aWallet = Wallet.createLight(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), ecKeyPair);  And this is mine WalletFile wallet = Wallet.createLight(seed,exKey);   Where seed is UUID.randomUUID().toString() and exKey is the same as exKeyPair

Comment: Sorry you are right. I woke up two minutes ago. The difference is that mine is in a try catch method so if there is an error it will catch.

Comment: Don't worry jejeje. I see the difference now,  but this is not my problem. There is not error, it is generating the wallet fine, but it takes too much time, so it won't go to the exception ever.

Comment: Can you print to the console in between each line and tell me where it slows down?

Comment: Exactly in this line is taking the time: WalletFile wallet = Wallet.createLight(seed,exKey);

Comment: Try changing `createLight` to `createStandard`

Comment: That doesn't work at all, but thanks to that tip I found the solution: Use Wallet.create without Light or createStandard